# Java ScrollPane (with a TextArea inside) can not scroll to top programmatically

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

To abstract this problem, I put 2 buttons. One is called "Add & toTop", another is called "toTop"

And there is no text in the textArea at the very beginning.

And I add the actionListener for "Add & toTop" button like this:

```
btn1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                textArea1.setText("jhggjhg\nhugffsrdtfg\ngfdrtdf\nhgftrsdf\nytfresrdcfvg\nuytyrdtesrdfgg\ntdrfygvhct\njh"
                        + "gfda\njftyuyiugcf\nhfuygihvftyughbuy\nhgyuftydfhgfyc\ndstryrfdts");
                //A long enough String
                JScrollBar jb = scrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar();
                jb.setValue(jb.getMinimum());
                scrollPane1.repaint();
            }
        });
```

So the function of the first button is :"Add some text and Scroll to Top"

**But it will only add text but will not scroll to top**

However for the second button, I add a actionListener like this:

```
btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JScrollBar VerticalScrollBar =  scrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar();
                VerticalScrollBar.setValue(VerticalScrollBar.getMinimum());

                scrollPane1.repaint();
            }
        });
```

So, I press the second button after pressing the first button, the second button will perform well. 
And I really feel confused that why the first button will not scroll to top :<

Comment: You could use something like `JTextArea#scrollRectToVisible`, passing it something like `new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1)`

Comment: Yeah, what he (@MadProgrammer) said!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution might be to use `JTextArea#setCaretPosition`, for example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea ta;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            ta = new JTextArea(5, 20);
            add(new JScrollPane(ta));

            JButton btn = new JButton("Add and to top");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    ta.setText("jhggjhg\nhugffsrdtfg\ngfdrtdf\nhgftrsdf\nytfresrdcfvg\nuytyrdtesrdfgg\ntdrfygvhct\njh"
                            + "gfda\njftyuyiugcf\nhfuygihvftyughbuy\nhgyuftydfhgfyc\ndstryrfdts");
                    ta.setCaretPosition(0);
                }
            });

            add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }


    }

}
```

I had a play around with `scrollRectToVisible`, but ended up having to use `SwingUtilites.invokeLater` to make it work, for example...

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ta.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10));
    }
});
```

so I'd say `setCaretPosition` in this case is the simpler solution